# Angular 2+ Custom form component in parent form.controls

Tags: angular, forms, controls, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom form component. I using my component on template driven form.
How can I inlude, my component into the form.controls collection, similar as an input field is in the form.controls?
I would like to found my component to decide is it dirty or not. My component is wrapping a 3th. party UI component which not implemented the ControlValueAccessor.

```
const EDITOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => OptionChoiceComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'option-choice',
  templateUrl: './option-choice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./option-choice.component.scss'],
  providers: [ EDITOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})

export class OptionChoicer implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  private hasChoice: boolean;
  onPropagateChange: Function = () => {};
  onModelTouched: Function = () => {};

  constructor() { }

  get value(): boolean {
    this.hasChoice;
  }

  set value(v: boolean) {
    this.hasChoice = v;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hasChouce = false;
  }

  onChoiced(event) {
    this.onModelTouched(true);
    this.onPropagateChange(true);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
        this.hasChoice = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
    this.onPropagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
    this.onModelTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(val: boolean): void {
  }

}
```

call of my component se below:

```
optionIsChoice is boolean

<option-choice id="optionchoice" [(ngModel)]="optionIsChoice"></option-choice>
```

Comment: where is your setter? Your propogate method should be in there.

Comment: Sorry, I have a setter I missed from here. set value(v: boolean) { this.hasChoice = v; } And I misspelled the hasChouce it is hasChoice

Comment: should be this.onProgapgateeChange(v);

Comment: In the onChoiced(event) ? This event called when the user chosen something, and in this case I set it directly to true, is it wrong?

Comment: Whenever you assign a new value to "value" variable, it will call SET every single time. Therefore, it makes sense to propagate changes in there, rather than inside of one method. Then, you won't even need an OnChoiced method.Otherwise, if you create more methods in the future, you will keep having to add propogate changes method to each of them, whenever you want to change value, which isn't ideal. It's not that your way is wrong, it just makes more sense to propogate changes one time in set method, rather than in each method you define.